# Can I use Google Spreadsheets for my Google Site?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sites

Is it possible to create Google Spreadsheet1 as my back end and Google Spreadsheet2 as my front end and display it to Google sites?

Answer (score 0):

If you can to create a Google Spreadsheet on the Google sites , you need to use The Google App Script to Create this.
You can show the Spreadsheet too.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/

If you can just show your spreadsheet , you can juste add your spreadsheet ( menu => insert )